# Subscribing to messages sent using Service Bus Active Passive Replication approach in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have a microservice publishing events to service bus using active passive replication or passive replication approach where it would send the message to a topic using primary region service bus if that fails, then it would send that same message to secondary region service bus. Both service bus have same topics and subscriptions configured and they are on standard tier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters#passive-replication

https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/messaging/cloud-architecture-patterns-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-for-azure-service-bus/#Active-Passive-Azure-Service-Bus-Replication

Now we want to build a service (function app) which needs to subscribe to a topic. Is there a way for a service bus trigger function to listen to two service buses rather than creating a function for each service bus subscription separately?

Or is there another easier and more cleaner way to achieve this if the subscriber is a function app?

Any thoughts and suggestion are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Function has to create a listener on a pre-defined entity. You could have two function triggers, one for each namespace, with shared logic.

Comment: I was hoping if I could get away with a single function but looks like two functions are the way to go, thanks!

Comment: It could be a single Function App but it would need to be two functions, sharing the logic of message processing.